# how to check the dependencies before installing the rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`sudo gem install rails --include-dependencies` will install rails and all the dependencies but before installing it. How may i check the dependencies before install the rails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`gem dependency`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page78)`rails --remote`